# How to play a sound for a Game Jam Menu Template button in Unity

Tags: unity, c#, audio, menu, plugin

I'm using the "Game Jam Menu Template" plugin from the asset store in a project of mine and I'm having a bit of a problem with it. See, I'd like it so that a particular button in the menu plays a sound before transitioning to the next scene. I've tried a number of ways to accomplish this so far, but none seem to be working. I initially tried attaching the `AudioSource.Play` method to the `On Click ()` events for my button, but that didn't work. It seems that the `StartOptions.StartButtonClicked` method is interfering with the `AudioSource`'s ability to play for some reason (that method is used to transition to the next scene in this plugin). So, I tried patching that function itself, by both running `this.gameObject.GetComponent<AudioSource>.Play()` at the beginning of it, as well as finding the object I wanted by tag and then attempting to play its `AudioSource`. However, both of these attempts at forcing the sound to play were unsuccessful as well and I'm kind of at a loss as to what to do now. Is there a way for a button that transitions to the next scene via `StartOptions.StartButtonClicked` to play an `AudioSource` before doing so in this "Game Jam Menu Template" plugin?